# multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
a = int(input('Enter your age: '))
b = 18 - a
if  a > 18:
    print("You are welcome")
else:
    print("Enjoy your youth, wait" + int(b)) #int на str заменить
```

Comment: У вас в коде другая ошибка, "сложение" строки с целым числом: `"Enjoy your youth, wait" + int(b)`

Comment: @insolor спасибо большое

Answer (score 0):

Этот код не вызывает такой ошибки. Проблема в используемой среде. В IDLE нельзя копировать весь скрипт разом. Либо копируйте построчно, либо используйте нормальную IDE.

Comment: какой IDE стоит юзать?

Comment: На этапе обучения не нужно использовать никакую IDE. Во-первых, IDE избавляет вас от рутинных операций, но именно рутинные операции позволяют набить руку . Во-вторых, IDE скрывает многие процессы, выполняя их за программиста, но именно они позволяют понять базовые принципы. Так что IDE надо начинать использовать только тогда, когда ты уже профи, всё знаешь и тебе надо увеличить производительность труда. Но если уж выбирать, то [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).

Comment: VIM с соответствующими плагинами. Шаблоны и сниппеты писать самостоятельно. Чтоб понять, что хорошего в VIM, можно посмотреть соответствующие ролики на youtube.