# pyTelegramAPI - SyntaxError erro: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement

Tags: python, telegram

Проблема в том ,что когда я делаю import telebot (pyTelegramAPI),происходит ошибка SyntaxError:multiple statements found while compiling a single statement,и я не знаю что делать .Пробовал переустанавливать  но не помогает
here is the code:

```
import telebot

bot=telebot.TeleBot("токен")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def welcome(message):

     bot.send_message(message.chat.id,"Добро пожаловать на дикий запад ковбой , {0.first_name}!\n Я - <b>{1.first_name}<b>,Шериф этого города.".format(message.from_user, bot.get_me()), 
    parse_mode="html")
```

фото:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для начала нужно добавить в вопрос **полный** текст ошибки.

Comment: так это и есть полный текст ошибки

Comment: Он ругается на import telebot

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [multiple statements found while compiling a single statement](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1010093/204271)

Answer (score 0):

Исполняйте строчки по одной, а не все скопом сразу. 
Обратите внимание на `>>>`, вы же находитесь в интерпритаторе.

Comment: Расширьте ответ, пожалуйста. Для новичка он малопонятен будет